# Secure a remote access with IP address

Tags: html, security, web, ip, remote-access

I want to prevent people to access my website outside my home and my father's home. Is it a good idea to check the IP of the connection and to grant the access or is it easily breachable ?

Comment: Do you/your father have static IPs - usually IPs are dynamic for home based internet connections, so you can't guarantee that they won't change anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Egerton already said, your method will work only if IP from your and your father homes are static.

Two other methods for checking allowed connections comes to my mind.

A [Login Page](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html) requesting for username & password. The example assume you can use php.

Allow only clients with a [Certificate](http://www.garex.net/apache/) installed. The example assume you're using and you can alter configuration of an Apache webserver.

Comment: Yep they are static. The "true" question is : can somebody can steal my ip address (like my little brother who can access from the inside) ?